# How to properly open deeplinks in webpage

Tags: android, html, deep-linking

This link,

**intent://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYqxf5eiLSU#Intent;package=com.google.android.youtube;scheme=https;end**

opens the specified content inside the app.But typing this link in to the browser is not opening up the app. So how are these links supposed to be used?

I know using it in anchor tags like below will enable users to click the link, and user will be taken to desired place.

```html
<a href="intent://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYqxf5eiLSU#Intent;package=com.google.android.youtube;scheme=https;end">Click to open in android.</a>
```

But how can we open these links directly without the help of a webpage? Or is there any other ways to open deeplinks?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it

```html
 <a className="flex btn m-4" onClick={() => window.location.href = 'myApp://Main'}>Som btn text</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just copy the URL without changing anything.

Also you can add `target="_blank"` attribute to open in new page.

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank"> Open stackoverflow </a>
```

In your case, you can pass this link to refer to your video.

```html
<a href="https://youtu.be/uYqxf5eiLSU" target="_blank"> Open my awesome yt video!!</a>
```